# php returning a EMPTY echo. HOW / WHY?

Tags: php, forms

I am having a very difficult time to figure out WHY I am getting this empty echo. I am debugging and I see all the values in the right place but it does not echo!

```
<body>
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div id='message'>
        <h2>Mail Sent Successfully!</h2>
        <p>We will be in touch soon.</p>
        <?php
            // Echo session variables that were set on previous page
            if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
                session_unset();
                session_destroy();
                $_SESSION['name'] = isset ($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : "";
                $_SESSION["favcolor"] = "Green ";
                echo "name: " . $_SESSION['name'] . ".<br>";
                echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION["favcolor"] . ".<br>";
            }
        ?>
    </div>

    <form method="POST" id="myform" class="myform" title="Apply Title" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label class="title">First Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="first_name" id='first_name' class="required"  minlength="2" data-msg-required="Please enter your first name" maxlength='128' value="<?PHP if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) echo htmlspecialchars($_POST['first_name']); ?>">
            </div>
            <p id="invalid-first_name" class="error_msg"></p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                <label class="title">Your employer's company name.</label>
                <input type="text" name="employer" id='employer'>
            </div>
            <p id="invalid-employer" class="error_msg"></p>
        </fieldset>
        <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit_app" class="sub" value="submit"/>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.min.js'></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="formToWizard.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#myform").formToWizard({ submitButton: 'submit_app' });
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                    error.appendTo('#invalid-' + element.attr('name'));
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

While debugging the code I can see all the value that just got typed. But once you submit the form it does not echo!

Comment: it must echo in the same page!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Where's your `session_start`?

Comment: You keep talking about "empty echo" and "does not echo", which is it? Do you see `name:` without the session variables? That's because you destroy the session before.

Comment: besides checking for errors with the link I provided; look at your HTML source and run a `var_dump();`. That should give you a good indication as to what's working or not.

Comment: Even if you wouldn't have unset and destroyed the session, it wouldn't have worked without starting the session first with `session_start()`. This is needed before you do _any_ action on the session array (read/write).

Comment: you also asked too many questions where probable solutions were given and you want more help? *Right*. Learn how to debug; it's part of the (coding) fun; good luck with this.

Comment: ...plus that your code still overwrites any previous session data right before you're echoing it.

Comment: <?php
    session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>

Comment: I have the session_start() right before start of <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: Accept the answer that worked for you, in case others have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to echo non existent session. Put session_start() before assigning variables.

```
<?php
            // Echo session variables that were set on previous page
            if (isset($_POST['first_name'])) {
                session_unset();

                $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['first_name'];
                $_SESSION['favcolor'] = "Green";

                echo "name: " . $_SESSION['name'] . ".<br>";
                echo "Favorite color is " . $_SESSION['favcolor'] . ".<br>";
            }
        ?>
```

**EDIT:**

I cleaned your code a little bit, try now. Dont destroy session, you can simply unset it if u need to. Also, im not sure what are you trying to do with `$_SESSION['name'] = isset ($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : "";` so i changed that.

Comment: I have session_start() right before <!DOCTYPE html>. Yes, I am debugging - I can see the values inside $_SESSION as the same as $_POST but it just not echo!

Comment: AltzeM Thanks for your help/support. I made the changes and I still can't see the name: ???? or even name: is just <BLANK> in the screen. while debugging I can see the OLD values before session_unset() and the NEW values after $_SESSION. Do you believe is something related after I call the function formToWizard.js. This function require that the submit button is type button.

Comment: just for the records here my functin:
(function($) {
    $.fn.formToWizard = function(options) {
        options = $.extend({
            submitButton: ""
        }, options);

  $('#submit_app').on('click',function(){
        if($("#myform").valid()){
       $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
          url: "index.php",
          data: $('#myform').serialize(),
          success: function(msg) {
                    // alert(msg);
                    $("#myform").addClass("hide");
                    $("#message").show();
               }
    });
     }
    });

Comment: If you cant see even "name: " and "Favorite color is " on the screen then it means you dont have $_POST['name'] variable so your if condition is false. Than it is probably javascript code wrong.

Comment: how come? while debugging I can see the $_POST with the new values?

Comment: I dont know how and where are you debugging so i cant answer that, but if you dont see any text at all it means that your if statement is false, so the problem is somewhere else (probably on post parameter)

Comment: OK. I made the changes as you pointed and now at least I see values. BUT the only issue is showing old values like session_unset() is not take action!

test 1: xxxx
try test 2: zzzz  it will output xxxx

Comment: AltzeM. is there any way to send you a PM?